# How do I redirect user_view_page to user_profile_form?

Tags: users

I do not really need the user_view_page on my site and I want to redirect calls to user/%user to the user_profile_form. I only want this change for regular users, not for administrators.

I already tried to accomplish this with hook_menu_alter, but that would change it for all users including the administrator.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module, you can mimic its behavior/do it yourself inside of [hook_init()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), eg something along the lines of:

```
function YOURMODULE_init() {
  global $user;

  if (arg(0)=='user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !(arg(2)) { // eg user/# and not user/#/edit

    if ( /* whatever logic you need to determine this is not an admin */ ) {

      if ($user->uid==arg(1)) { // same user...
        drupal_goto($_GET['q'] . '/edit');
      } else {
        // either ignore it and allow standard Drupal permissions to deal with it or go someplace else, do a drupal_access_denied() etc
      }

    }

  }

  // any other module init stuff here...

}
```

You didn't specify what you want to happen if a user tries to look at another user's page but you can deal with that situation easily above as well.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I'll use. Because the link to the user profile page can also be plain '/user' without the user id, i had to change the logic a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem in the past with the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Event:
User Account page is viewed

Condition:
User has role(s)

Action:
Page redirect
Parameter URL:[account:edit-url]

I created the rule and added the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oONeT.jpg

Here is also the exported rule:

```
{ "rules_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "test",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_view" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "account" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "[account:edit-url]" } } ]
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!